# $9$ coins into three groups

Tags: logical-deduction, weighing

You are a lab assistant and your prof asked you something very specific: There are $9$ coins made of ***three*** different materials with different densities in front of you, but they look the same, divide these $9$ coins into three different material group. It is also known that there are *3 coins for each material* type.

> What is the **least amount of weighing** required to guarantee you divide these coins into three different material group by using a two pan arm scale?

Answer (score 4):

I found a range of possible weighings so far.

> 7-9 weighings

I got a lower bound with the following reasoning.

> First find the total number of ways the 3 groups can be partitioned. There are $9!$ permutations of 9 coins but there are $3!$ ways each group can be ordered. This gives a total of $\frac{9!}{3!^3} = 1680$ combinations. Also thanks to @hexomino for catching my earlier mistake in the comments.
>
>  With $n$ weighings there are 3 outcomes per weighing for a total of $3^n$ outcomes. To get at least 1680 outcomes we need $\left \lceil{\log_3 1680}\right \rceil = \left \lceil{6.759936}\right \rceil = 7$ weighings.
>
>  This is a lower bound so 7 might not be possible due to some unforeseen issue.

Now here is a scheme that gives an upper bound.

> Step 1) Pick the first coin and put it in group A.
>  Step 2) Pick another coin and weigh it against a coin in A. Put it in group A if the scales are balanced or group B otherwise.
>  Step 3) Repeat step 2 until there are two coins in group B.
>  Step 4) If the coins both weighed less or both weighed more then A, continue on otherwise goto end 1.
>  Step 5) Weigh the two group B coins against each other. If they are the different goto end 2.
>  Step 6) Repeat step 2 until we get a third coin. If all three coins tipped the scale the same direction, continue on otherwise goto end 3.
>  Step 7) Weigh the third coin against one of the other coins in group B. If it is different goto end 4 otherwise goto end 5.
>
>  End 1) We got lucky with A being a middle coin. Move one of the group B coins to C. Weigh the rest of the coins against A moving them to their matching group. We can stop when any two groups have 3 coins. This will result in a maximum of 7 weighings.
>  End 2) We now know a middle coin. Move this coin to group C. Weigh the rest of the coins against C moving them to their matching group. We can stop when any two groups have 3 coins. This will result in a maximum of 8 weighings.
>  End 3) We now know A is a middle coin. Move third coin to group C. Weigh the rest of the coins against A moving them to their matching group. We can stop when any two groups have 3 coins. This will result in a maximum of 8 weighings.
>  End 4) We now know a middle coin. Move this coin (and possible matching coin) to group C. Weigh the rest of the coins against C moving them to their matching group. We can stop when any two groups have 3 coins. This will result in a maximum of 9 weighings.
>  End 5) Group B is now complete. Keep weighing coins against A but now putting different weighing coins in group C. We can stop when any two groups have 3 coins. This will result in a maximum of 9 weighings.
>
>  Since all endings give a maximum of 9 weightings, 9 is an upper bound.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 9!/(3!^3) because the order in *each of the three groups* is arbitrary?

Comment: Yep, thanks for the catch. I thought I might have done something wrong. I think I might also have found a strategy that uses less than 11. Further proving that my lower bound is wrong.

Comment: Does it include weighings with several coins on one pan? Or is it banned?

Comment: @rus9384 The method given above only weighs one coin on each side at a time. I'm guessing a better method might not follow this to achieve better result. However, we don't know the densities so a dense coin might be heavier than two less dense coins.

Comment: I guess there is an algorithm that does this in 8 weighings, but not sure the one doing it in 7 exists.

Comment: The one that had 8 weighings had a mistake in it (and now seems to be deleted). My intution tells me that 7 is impossible and 8 would be very hard.

Comment: Not if we put 4 coins on each side at time. In this case 7 is not the lower bound, probably.

Answer (score 1):

A method that meets Bennett's now improved-upon lower bound is as follows. First let the masses be L < M < H

Choose a coin A and weight it against each of seven other coins - placing each of the weighted coins in one of three piles l (for lighter), s (for same) and h for heavier than coin A.

If you are lucky and A was M, then the piles will be 223, or 313, or 322. Then you know the unweighed coin is L, M, or H, respectively (and know A is M) so have done the job in 7 weighings total.

If A was L then the piles lsh will have number of coins  016 or 025 (depending on whether the final coin was L or not). And you know the final unweighed coin is L, or either M or H, respectively (and know A is L). So now choose a coin B from the 6 in the heavier pile (consisting M and H coins). Weight it against each of four remaining coins in that pile.

If B is M, then you will get sh = 22, or sh = 13. So the unweighed coin of the six is H or M respectively (and know B is M). This would complete the sorting in a total of 11 weighings.

If B is H, you will get ls = 22, or 31, confirming the final coin is M or H respectively (and B is H). Also for 11 weighings total.

By symmetry, if A is H you can follow an effectively identical process to that above and still get the sorting done in 11 goes.

Comment: I think you forgot a coin. There are nine in total and you only weigh 1 against 7 for a total of 8. Furthermore, I made a mistake in my math and got the lower bound wrong. See my edit for a correct (I hope) lower bound and upper bound (that is lower than my previous lower bound).

Comment: Nevermind about the forgotten coin, I just misunderstood your method. The rest of my comment applies though.

Comment: Bennett's lower bound is about worst case scenario. In yours it is 11 weighings.

Comment: @rus9384 my original lower bound was 11. That's what I'm talking about in my comment above